# No music or audio from Plantronics Backbeat Go 2 paired with Nokia 800 Window Phone

Tags: bluetooth, nokia-lumia-800

Would like to seek advise on how to get my newly bought Plantronics BackBeat Go2 to work Music from my Nokia 800. It works fine with a call, but I am not getting music (and for that matters audio from Movie) through this headset when paired with the Nokia 800 window phone.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see when you go to `settings` > `audio` and `settings` > `accessories` when the device is plugged in?